# how to flip two views at once?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, view, flip

i'm trying to flip two views in one screen with a single button click,i.e  i want to have  multiple animations at the same time(ex:iPhone music player where the button and view flips at the same time)

p.s-i don't want to animate views one after another,it should be done together

EDIT

this is the code i used,please help me out

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{

    if (viewDisplay) 

    {

        [fareView removeFromSuperview];

        [containerView addSubview:mapView];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:containerView cache:YES];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:buttonView cache:YES];

        viewDisplay = FALSE;

        swapLabel.text = @"Fare View";

        [mapOrFare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"original_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    else

    {

        [mapView removeFromSuperview];

        [containerView addSubview:fareView];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:containerView cache:YES];

        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:buttonView cache:YES];

        viewDisplay = TRUE;

        swapLabel.text = @"Map View";

        [mapOrFare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I tried animating two subviews using
[UIView beginAnimation..]
.
.
[UIView commitAnimation] block
but, only one view is animated. the other simply appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `bgView1` and `bgView2` are the views to be flipped, as below; you should just be able to put the animator code one after the other and it should all work out ok. See below for the example,

```
-(void)flipViews {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:bgView1 cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [bgView1 exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:bgView2 cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [bgView2 exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use block animations, it should work with no issues.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:myDuration
    animations:^{
        <animation 1 code>;
        <animation 2 code>;
}];
```

Comment: Not useful as the animations code is the key what would the animations code look like for this code example ??