# Want to flip two views so that one view hides and other shows swift

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I want to flip two views from top or left, direction is not a big deal
Basicaly i want to flip one view so that in animation one view hides or and other shows like card flip
I want this but with two view
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kSLbuB-MlU

I found it in objective C (maybe)
link is attached
[how to flip two views at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768021/how-to-flip-two-views-at-once)
Image is also attached

I have tried something below but could not find a suitable solution

```
UIView.transition(from: vu1, to: vu2, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, completion: { _ in
        })
```

Also tried this but did not help

```
   func flipTransition (with view1: UIView, view2: UIView, isReverse: Bool = true) {
        var transitionOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions()
        transitionOptions = isReverse ? [.transitionFlipFromLeft] : [.transitionFlipFromRight]

        UIView.transition(with: view1, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            view1.isHidden = true
        })

        UIView.transition(with: view2, duration: 1.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            view2.isHidden = false
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView.transition(with` applies to a container view so you can try putting your subviews in a container view and apply `UIView.transition` on container view. Because you havent added any code am assuming few things here to answer

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    let view1 = UIView()
    let view2 = UIView()
    let containerView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(view1)
        containerView.addSubview(view2)

        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),

            view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            view1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 100),

            view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            view2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            view2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        ])

        view1.isHidden = false
        view2.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func changeTapped() {
        UIView.transition(with: containerView,
                          duration: 1.0,
                          options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.view1.isHidden = !self.view1.isHidden
            self.view2.isHidden = !self.view2.isHidden
        })
    }
```

**O/P:**

[image]

Comment: @munib-hamza :) am glad I could help :)